# Enabling ContextMenu on a Topmost Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a window with `Topmost="True"`.

```
<Window ... bunch of code ....
    Topmost="True" >
```

Doing this now effectively disables all context menus on the form. The menus are defined in the XAML, like this:

```
<StackPanel Width="120" Height="50" MouseMove="Drag_MouseMove">
    <Image Source="{Binding" />
    <TextBlock Text={Binding}" />
    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="myMenu" StaysOpen="True">
            ... bunch of code ... 
        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to re-enable context menus? I'm also willing to consider alternatives to `Topmost="True"`.

Comment: does this answer your question? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/7f33954b-4fd9-4047-a111-2183e8fa6b6b

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by hiding all menus?

Comment: @sil: I'm not trying to hide the menus. They are hiding all by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I've created a new project using this near-code to yours and context menu does show.

Maybe the problem comes from something else? like the bindings? (talking from experience)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Topmost="True">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="120" Height="50" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <TextBlock Text="yo" />
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="myMenu" StaysOpen="True">
                    <MenuItem Header="hello" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the menu is showing just fine. However, the menu is not a top level item so it ends up behind your topmost MainWindow. I've got the same problem and have not yet found the answer as to how to make sure that the menu always shows.